# java Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate com..toString() android studio

Tags: java, android, json

en verdad estoy atascado,

me salta lo siguiente

"Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.quantum.parseo.GridIn12.toString()"

toda la serializacion lo hice por la siguiente pagina

https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

del siguiente json

```
{ 
"username" : "xxx",
"password" : "xxx",
"Deposito_Desde": "ADUANA", 
"Deposito_Hasta": "JMINGE", 
"GridIn_1_2": [
```

{

```
  "Inicial__final": "F",
  "Número_artículo": "SE36X361A0194",
  "Cantidad": "1",
  "Ubicación": ".",
  "Número_lote_serie": "8000010"

},

{

  "Inicial__final": "F",
  "Número_artículo": "SE36X361A0194",
  "Cantidad": "1",
  "Ubicación": ".",
  "Número_lote_serie": "8000011"

},

{

  "Inicial__final": "T",
  "Lineas_relacionadas": "1",
  "Número_artículo": "SE36X361A0194",
  "Cantidad": "2",
  "Ubicación": "P2.",
  "Número_lote_serie": "T664C01"

}
```

]

}

lo probé en el postman y funciona correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dándome dos clases con sus getter y setters

```
public class Cuerpo {
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
public String username ;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
public String password;
@SerializedName("Deposito_Desde")
@Expose
public String depositoDesde;
@SerializedName("Deposito_Hasta")
@Expose
public String depositoHasta ;
@SerializedName("GridIn_1_2")
@Expose
public List<GridIn12> gridIn12 ;
//getters y setters


 public  class GridIn12  {
     @SerializedName("Inicial__final")
@Expose
public String inicialFinal,inicialFinal2,inicialFinal3;
@SerializedName("Número_artículo")
@Expose
public String nMeroArtCulo,nMeroArtCulo2,nMeroArtCulo3;
@SerializedName("Cantidad")
@Expose
public String cantidad,cantidad2,cantidad3;
@SerializedName("Ubicación")
@Expose
public String ubicaciN,ubicaciN2,ubicaciN3;
@SerializedName("Número_lote_serie")
@Expose
public String nMeroLoteSerie,nMeroLoteSerie2,nMeroLoteSerie3;
@SerializedName("Lineas_relacionadas")
@Expose
public String lineasRelacionadas;

//getters y setters
```

Estoy usando la libreria Retrofit, dentro del llamado del metodo puse lo siguiente

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);


            GridIn12 gridIn12 = null; //creé un objeto para insertar los datos
            gridIn12 = new GridIn12();
            gridIn12.setInicialFinal("F");
            gridIn12.setNMeroArtCulo("SE36X361A0194");
            gridIn12.setCantidad("1");
            gridIn12.setUbicaciN(".");
            gridIn12.setNMeroLoteSerie("8000010");


            gridIn12.setInicialFinal2("F");
            gridIn12.setnMeroArtCulo2("SE36X361A0194");
            gridIn12.setCantidad2("1");
            gridIn12.setUbicaciN2(".");
            gridIn12.setnMeroLoteSerie2("8000011");

            gridIn12.setInicialFinal3("T");
            gridIn12.setLineasRelacionadas("1");
            gridIn12.setnMeroArtCulo3("SE36X361A0194");
            gridIn12.setCantidad3("2");
            gridIn12.setUbicaciN3("P2.");
            gridIn12.setnMeroLoteSerie3("T664C01");

            List<GridIn12> list = Collections.singletonList(gridIn12); // despues lo convertí en una lista

            Cuerpo model = new Cuerpo(); //creé uno para el objeto
            model.setUsername("xxx");
            model.setPassword("xxx");
            model.setDepositoDesde("ADUANA");
            model.setDepositoHasta("JMINGE");
           model.setGridIn12(list)  ;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagino que es un error de concepto, siempre manajé simple jsons en el request, pero veo que ese tiene un array dentro del objeto.

podrian guiarme de alguna manera? si se necesita mas codigo o imagenes con gusto los pondré,

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @G. Capovi, pregunta tonta, en la página en la que serializaste, marcaste la opción **Incluir toString** ?, hay un método toString?, porque ese es el error que te está arrojando.

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente! no, no lo incluí, deberia?

Comment: creo que es el error, no está pudiendo convertir en **String** a **GridIn12**, prueba con eso a ver si se arregla.

Comment: Gracias! voy acercandome mas de resolverlo, me ayudó tu comentario

Comment: Un placer poder colaborar!